# Prefixing each item in a Pandas DataFrame with an ascending number if it has a value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm currently trying to find the best solution to this problem:

I import a csv into Python, some of the cells have values and some don't. I want to loop through the dataframe and if a cell has a value, append a number to it which is incremented each time a new cell has text. These appended values are then saved to a new column

I also save each piece of text to another list as I need to use them in the next step (`out`). The following code produces the correct output, I just wondered if there is a more efficient way to do it?

I considered `np.where()` or something similar but can't increment a count from that.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["", "c", "e"], ["a", "", ""], ["b", "d", "f"]], 
    columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
)
count = 1
out = []

# Loop over each column
for col in df.columns:
      tmp = []
      # Loop over each entry, if cell has text, add prefix
      for text in df[col]:
        if text:
          tmp.append(str(count) + "-" + text)
          out.append(text)
          count += 1
        else:
          tmp.append("")
      # Add prefixed column to df    
      df["pre-" + col] = tmp
```

Giving output:
[Output DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXdW9.png)

This doesn't necessarily have to be done column-wise, as long as the numbers correspond to the order in `out`.

EDIT:

Mozway's answer, with lambda function because I wanted some number formatting.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [["", "c", "e"], ["a", "", ""], ["b", "d", "f"]], 
    columns = ["x", "y", "z"]
)
s = df.replace('', np.nan).T.stack()
out = (s.notna().cumsum().apply(
    lambda x: "{0:04}-".format(x))+s).unstack().T.fillna('')
df = df.join(out.add_prefix("pre-"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the order of the counter, reshape with [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), increment with [`cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html), then [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = df.replace('', np.nan).stack()

out = (s.notna().cumsum().astype(str)+'-'+s
      ).unstack().fillna('')
```

Output:

```
     x    y    z
0       1-c  2-e
1  3-a          
2  4-b  5-d  6-f
```

If order matters:

```
s = df.replace('', np.nan).T.stack()

out = (s.notna().cumsum().astype(str)+'-'+s
      ).unstack().T.fillna('')
```

Or using [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
m = df.ne('').to_numpy()

tmp = (pd.DataFrame(m.T.cumsum(axis=None).reshape(m.shape).T,
                    index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
         .astype(str).add('-')
         .where(m, '')
      )

out = tmp+df
```

Output:

```
     x    y    z
0       3-c  5-e
1  1-a          
2  2-b  4-d  6-f
```

And to combine the output to the original DataFrame, [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
df.join(out.add_prefix('pre-'))
```

Output:

```
   x  y  z pre-x pre-y pre-z
0     c  e         3-c   5-e
1  a         1-a            
2  b  d  f   2-b   4-d   6-f
```